# Groovy bootstrap error using GIT BASH on Windows 7

Tags: git, unix, groovy, cygwin

I am calling a git hook to pre-commit. This triggers a call to a groovy script and does so in a manner that allows for remote debugging of the hook execution. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
groovy -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8085,suspend=y "C:\Users\.......hooks\PreCommit.groovy"
```

when I trigger the hook with the use of GIT BASH I see the following error:

```
/c/Program Files (x86)/Groovy/Groovy-2.1.0/bin/startGroovy: line 96: [: too many arguments org.codehaus......: startup failed: .... expected EOF, found ':' @ line 3 column 35]
```

when I take a quick look at the startGroovy file I see the following unclear code - where line 96 is the if condition with GROOVY home:

```
# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched.
if $cygwin ; then
  [ -n "$GROOVY_HOME" ] && GROOVY_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$GROOVY_HOME"`
  [ -n "$JAVACMD" ] && JAVACMD=`cygpath --unix "$JAVACMD"`
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CP" ] && CP=`cygpath --path --unix "$CP"`
else
  if [ -n "$GROOVY_HOME" -a `expr "$GROOVY_HOME":'\/$'` ] ; then
      GROOVY_HOME=`echo $GROOVY_HOME | sed -e 's/\/$//'`
  fi
fi
```

Is this a bug in the groovy bootstrap? 
my windows 7 has it env variable GROOVY_HOME correctly pointing to: C:\program file (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the script from Groovy.  The script is not quoting the env variable GROOVY_HOME properly in all the right places.  The spaces in the path represented by GROOVY_HOME, in my case "Program Files (x86)" has 2 spaces, are being interpreted as delimiters and causing the path to be parsed out as more than 1 argument.  To fix it, change the definition of the windows environment variable GROOVY_HOME to use the tilde version of the path.  Edit your environment variable GROOVY_HOME (on Vista, start/right-click computer/properties/advanced system settings/environment variables/either user or system, mine was system) and set to c:/Progra~2/Groovy/Groovy-2.1.3.  When you start your Git, MinGW or CygWin shell, you won't have the spaces and should not get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The cygpath command is missing from Git Bash which only implements a stripped down version of cgywin.  One solution is to use a full cygwin installation for git, but it's probably similar to create your own .bashrc with unix styled directory names:

```
# Check to see what the DOS directories are
echo GROOVY_HOME=$GROOVY_HOME
echo JAVACMD=$JAVACMD
echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
echo CP=$CP

# Add the directories you found to .bashrc in a unix style
cat - >>~.bashrc
export GROOVY_HOME='/c/program file (x86)/Groovy/Groovy-2.1.0'
export JAVACMD="..."
export JAVA_HOME="/c/Program files/Java/jre7/bin/java"
export CP= "..."
```

Please change the paths as appropriate.  You can edit .bashrc using notepad++ or another editor instead of using cat.  Remember that the cat - command is terminated using Control-D in Bash, whereas a DOS copy con file.txt uses Control-Z.  By placing these variables in .bashrc they won't interfere with your DOS environment variables.

Comment: That was an interesting observation. Nevertheless, I've just tested it with no luck. It turns out that the `if $cygwin` is false and therefor no cygpath is called anyways, so the error must be around the  `if [ -n "$GROOVY_HOME" -a 'expr "$GROOVY_HOME":'\/$'' ] ; then
      GROOVY_HOME='echo $GROOVY_HOME | sed -e 's/\/$//''
  fi` . I have inserted the exports in my .bashrc and although it seems correctly set an echo in the startGroovy file will show the the GROOVY_HOME format is still windows.